# Wrong indentation when editing Yaml in Vim

Tags: vim, yaml

Vim does not seem to correctly react at a dash symbol in YAML files therefore breaking the format.

For example I have a block which should look like this:

```
  handlers:
        - name: restart exim4
          service: name=exim4 state=restarted
```

When I finish typing `restart exim4` and type `service:` Vim reindents my final `service` line:

```
  handlers:
        - name: restart exim4
        service: name=exim4 state=restarted
```

So clearly Vim tries to align sentences *column-wise* but that's not what is needed in YAML. I want to create an array with two values.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Install this plugin:

https://github.com/chase/vim-ansible-yaml

It is made with Ansible in mind, but in theory it will work with all kinds of YAML files. You will have to :set filetype=ansible unfortunately, if you are not working with ansible related files.

Comment: I saw this plugin - it expects filename to have a certain name and/or to be in a specific folder. Ansible playbooks are not the only files i edit. That's why i didn't even try to install it.
Thanks, i will set yml to have type 'ansible'.

Comment: wow, makes a big difference, I think though the regular `yaml` syntax worth fixing as well

Comment: Truth, if you go this route you have to put `# vim:ft=ansible:` in all your non-ansible files.

Answer (score 220):

In order to get the nice 2-space YAML as the default when I hit carriage return after the colon, I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

This also plays nice with the dash for the OP's expected result.

Comment: Nice and simple. Works with `/etc/vim/vimrc` (for global config) whereas I couldn't get the `vim-ansible-yaml` plugin to work globally.

Comment: Consider putting it in ~/vim/ftplugin/yaml.vim and replacing short names with long names for future readability.

Comment: Works as advertised. Is it possible to make the one line work for both `.yaml` and `.yml` files? I can achieve that with two lines in my `.vimrc`, but it would be nice if I could one-line it.

Comment: `autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab indentkeys-=<:>`
works well for me

Comment: @LeviNoecker yes just comma separate them like this `autocmd FileType yaml,yml setlocal ...`

Comment: For this to work, I had to have `filetype plugin indent on` first. Also a nice touch is to have `syntax on` before that.

Comment: This is the sum of my comments above --> https://gist.github.com/dragonken/c29123e597c6fdf022284cf36d245b64

Comment: Whoever is interested, I found above line and more details here : https://www.arthurkoziel.com/setting-up-vim-for-yaml/index.html

Answer (score 29):

You can use this autocommand to make Vim properly indent YAML files (put it to your `.vimrc`):

```
" Fix auto-indentation for YAML files
augroup yaml_fix
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab indentkeys-=0# indentkeys-=<:>
augroup END
```

Basically, for YAML file it instructs Vim to:

- Use 2 spaces for indentation.
- Use spaces instead of tabs.
- Skip re-indenting lines after inserting a comment character (`#`) at the beginning of a line, or a colon.

Comment: Adding .yml also helps

Comment: To what? Where?

Comment: This doesnt work for me

Comment: "Skip re-indenting lines" <-- Yes! This is the reason I am here. Adding comments totally wrecks the indent structure. I have no idea what the original indent designer was thinking. Thanks! [Edit: EXCEPT, it's not working for me :( ]

Comment: "I have no idea what the original indent designer was thinking." After reading indent/yaml.vim, I'd say they were thinking that no one would ever start a comment after a line that wasn't also a comment. *Extremely* aggravating.

Answer (score 26):

You can disable reindent when you type `:` key:

```
:set indentkeys-=<:>
```

Please edit `~/.vimrc` file, and add these lines:

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType yaml setl indentkeys-=<:>
```

<sub>**Note:** `autocmd` comes after `filetype`.</sub>

---

You can trigger reindent by typing <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> in **INSERT** mode, for example:

```
hello: world
    foo: bar<C-F>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a comment in your YAML to tell Vim special config for this file. For example:

```
# vim: set shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=-1 expandtab:
foo:
  bar:
  - a
  - b
```

Then everyone, who use this file with a default vim, can share the file creator's configuration. It works well especially when cooperating.

Comment: Still indents with 8 spaces on `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)`

Comment: Save the file with the comment and reopen it with Vim.

Answer (score 1):

I've found https://github.com/stephpy/vim-yaml to work great. It's a vim plugin that does indentation (and syntax highlighting) of yaml files. Installing it solves the specific problem that you've asked about too.

You need to install the plugin (see the doco in the GitHub repo) and as long as your `filetype=yaml` it'll correct your indenting. It'll help you both

1. as you're typing the snippet you've provided, or
2. if you already have some yaml written, you can select it (with `V` for line-wise selection then use `j` or `k` to select more lines) then trigger the vim formatting with `=`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `augroup` I have for yaml:

```
augroup filetype_yaml
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml} set filetype=yaml foldmethod=indent
    autocmd FileType yaml |
        setlocal shiftwidth=2 |
        setlocal softtabstop=2 |
        setlocal tabstop=2
augroup END
```