# vim wrong indent when comment lines of yaml file

Tags: vim, yaml

I have tried the [autocmd way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488992/522159), not work for me.

1. One line comment with <kbd>i</kbd>, indent wrong.

Press <kbd>i</kbd> at begin of the line, then press <kbd>#</kbd>, the <kbd>#</kbd> and cursor auto indent.

[image: one line comment with i]

2. One line comment with <kbd>I</kbd>, indent right.

Press <kbd>I</kbd> at begin of the line, the cursor auto indent; then press <kbd>#</kbd>.

[image: one line comment with I]

3. Block comment with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, followed with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, followed with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, indent wrong.

[image: block comment]

---------------------Edit------------------------

4. Block comment with cursor on the `-`

The first block and the second block bahaves different.

[image]

Comment: @rkta I use `i`

Comment: Using `I` should help.

Comment: @romainl I edited the question to make it clear. `I` worked for one line comment, but not for block comment.

Comment: @rkta I add a new picture, showed that comment with cursor on the `-`, the first block and the second block behaves different. My question is how to make the indent right when comment. Because I need to often comment different blocks to test different components.

Comment: I know I'll get hate from romainl :) but Tim Pope's [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin just does the right thing. (I'll typically visual-select, linewise, the lines to comment or uncomment, then `gc`)

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, the Commentary plugin worked good.

Comment: The existing answer solves the problem so I'm not sure why that question was bountied.

Answer (score 16):

This drove me nuts too! Thankfully the solution is pretty simple:

```
autocmd FileType yaml,yaml.ansible setlocal indentkeys-=0#
```

You need to use "yaml.ansible" if you use the [ansible-vim](https://github.com/pearofducks/ansible-vim.git) plugin. Using "setlocal" instead of "set" is optional but after decades with Vim I've learned that it is a good idea to specify local when you know you only want it local to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: Thank you -- putting this in `~/.vimrc` (on Linux) works. Do you know why I am not achieving equivalent behavior by putting `setlocal indentkeys-=0#` in either `~/.vim/ftplugin/yaml.vim` or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim` however? I would love to put the `setlocal` in a separate file so as to not pollute `~/.vimrc`.