# vim: indent next line more than the current

Tags: vim

I am looking for a way to easily indent next line more than the current. This, in combination with autoindent, should make editing yaml files easier.

One of the possible solutions I thought would be to add several mappings for interactive mode.
For example:
`<space><newline>` to map to  `<newline><tabstop number of spaces>`

`<space><space><newline>` to map to `<newline><tabstop number of spaces><tabstop number of spaces>`

I tried `imap <8b>^M ^M<8b><8b>`, but that didn't work. And I don't know why.

So if you could help me figure out why the above did not work, or suggest me a more elegant solution, I would be greatful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong indentation when editing Yaml in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962999/wrong-indentation-when-editing-yaml-in-vim)

Comment: This might also be interesting for you: https://github.com/tarekbecker/vim-yaml-formatter

Comment: @SiKing and formatter, The articles you are referring to do sort of smartindent.
But I am not looking for any smarts. I want it dumb. I want to control next line's indent before I press newline.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is wrong with the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The format for the special keys in your mapping is slightly off. If you write a mapping for `<8b>^M`, you would need to press <kbd><</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. That's not what you want.

Starting from your textual explanation of what you want to accomplish, I created some mappings for <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. The following mappings will work for up to four levels of indentation. For more than four, I expect things to become messy.

```
inoremap <Space><CR> <CR><Tab>
inoremap <Space><Space><CR> <CR><Tab><Tab>
inoremap <Space><Space><Space><CR> <CR><Tab><Tab><Tab>
inoremap <Space><Space><Space><Space><CR> <CR><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab>
```

I'm also using `:inoremap` 1) on general principle and 2) because we don't want to trigger any mappings on their right-hand side. Some plugins just love to map tab for code completion etc.

Note that this will cause a tiny delay each time you press space because Vim will wait for the following key and whether to trigger a mapping. This can be quite irritating when writing text.

I also don't see any major advantage over breaking the line first and then adjusting indentation, either by pressing tab or backspace or Vim's `<` and `>` (see `:help shift-left-right`).

The usual way to go is to make Vim get the indentation right based on your buffer's contents. So, no, I don't think this is a good idea. This is how it could be done.